# Any way to split data into train , test , valid data and save in text jupyter

Tags: python

I just loaded roughly around 80500 photos from my datasets, how can I seperate them using the train test split method and after then dump them into a file. ex.(joblib.dump)

I would like 60% training sets, 20% validation, and 20% testing.
Is that something wrong with my datasets load code? As I couldn't split the data

```
   folders = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Pc\\Desktop\\Facial Recognition Dataset\\*')
imagenames_list = []
for folder in folders:
    for f in glob.glob(folder+'\\*.jpg'):
        imagenames_list.append(f)
        
read_images = []
for image in imagenames_list:
    read_images.append(cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
    
images = np.array(read_images)
```

[image: output after successfully loaded]

Tried this code to split but dosen't work, i've included the library

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(imagenames_list, read_images, 
                                                    test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

[image: output shape result]

Comment: can you provide the shape of images variable? `images.shape` as well as `imagenames_list` and `read_images` variables.

Comment: i attached that in the question, i get 3 same output by doing that

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use this multiple times. And to ensure that you have 20% flat split between the 2 times, you will have to check the new % after the original data has been split.

Try this -

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = np.random.random((1000,10)), np.random.random((1000,))

p = 0.2
new_p = (p*y.shape[0])/((1-p)*y.shape[0])

X, X_val, y, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=p)
X_train, X_test, y, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=new_p)

print([i.shape for i in [X_train, X_test, X_val]])
```

```
[(600, 10), (200, 10), (200, 10)]
```

Notice that even with the 2 splits, you have train with 60% data, test with 20% data and validation with 20% data.

Comment: Is there a way i can loop that 161 times? Currently my datasets have 161 folders ( 1-161) and 500 data are inside each folder. Can i run a loop for repeating the same step 161 times?

Comment: A for loop over the different paths would be the way to go.